# Adding Multiple Rows into Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm having issue in adding multiple rows of data into database for the form name courseoutline[image are attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACLZM.png). I have tried use array statement but it still not support my code and i couldn't find where is the mistake. Please help me to correct my code.

Script Code:

```
 <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.apsection').append('Course Outline: <input type="text" style="width: 800px;" name="courseoutline[]" class="form-contro" placeholder="Enter your Course Outline"><br>');
    
            });
    
        });
    </script>

Form Code:


 <div class="tab"><h5>Section 3: Course Content Outline</h5>
    <div class="apsection">
                  Course Outline : <input type="text" style="width: 800px;" name="courseoutline[]" class="form-contro" placeholder="Enter your Course Outline"><br>
                 
                </div>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-warning">Add More</button>
    </div>
```

Database Code:

```
<?php
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "adminpanel";
    
    //connection 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("connection failure " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        $count = count($_POST['courseoutline']);
    
    for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) {
        mysqli_query($sqlres);
   $sqlres = "INSERT INTO course_content (courseoutline, coursecode) VALUES ('{$_POST['courseoutline'][$i]}','$coursecode')";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    
    ?>
```

Comment: In the foor-loop you are only defining a string $sqlres for creating different INSERT-statements. That does not have any affect on a database. You have to do the actual query to the database for each insert-statement you define. Do you have any database-connection?

Comment: You should look into prepared statements because your defined insert sql would be vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, i do have database connection and already update in code.

Comment: If you have it please update your question so we see your actual query to the database.

Comment: Opening a `mysqli` connection doesn't execute anything. `$sqlres` is just a variable that is never used.

Comment: Sorry, I already update all my query inside my database. Can you please let me know which part is wrong?

Comment: You are just opening and closing your database. You are not making a query to the database. You have to use mysql_query($sqlres ) within your for-loop.

Comment: i have update the query but i want to make sure is it i placed the query in right way? but still one row of data only insert into database, can you let me know which part is still wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Use foreach instead of.

Database Code:

```
foreach($_POST['courseoutline'] as $value) {
    $sqlres = "INSERT INTO course_content (courseoutline, coursecode) VALUES ($value,'$coursecode')";
}
```

Comment: That's just another type of loop. That does not solve OP's issue.

Comment: This actually is worse because `$value` has been unquoted. This won't execute presuming `courseoutline` is a string. And ignoring the SQL injection issues.